# Use Point feature ol in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

Based on [this link example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html?q=marker), I am trying to use Point feature but I get :

`my.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: ol.source.Point is not a constructor`

```
   var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.source.Point([35.1495, 33.39243]),
        name: 'A point',
        population: 4000,
        rainfall: 500
    });
```

Comment: It should be `new ol.geom.Point`

Comment: @Mike i actually want to place multiple points. Latitude and Longitude are coming from the server as json format via ajax.

Comment: How this example placed the point?

Comment: Solution to your question has been given in the first comment. If you have additional question(s), put it/them in separate question(s).

Comment: This question continues here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344656/looping-through-an-array-to-show-multiple-points-on-the-map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If  you look at an earlier version which uses full build syntax you can see it is `new ol.geom.Point` https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/icon.html

If you have geojson data OpenLayers can load and parse it directly from the url

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'your json url',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: .... 
});
```

or if you have loaded the json yourself you can parse it into a features array, the geometry and any properties specified in a valid geojson will be included

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(your_json_data, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection());
```

Note that if your map view is not LonLat (e.g. it is web mercator) and you use readFeatures you must transform the coordinates to display the features in their correct location.

If your json is simply an array you must loop through to create each feature and add it to the source.  You may also need to transform the geometry projection to view it.

```
   var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([lon, lat]).transform('EPSG:4326', viewProjection),
        name: name
    });
    vectorLayer.addFeature(iconFeature);
```

If you have an `array` in the form `[[lon, lat]. [lon, lat], [lon, lat], .... , [lon, lat]]` you could create a single MultiPoint feature

```
   var feature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.MultiPoint(array).transform('EPSG:4326', viewProjection)
    });
    vectorLayer.addFeature(fFeature);
```